# does powershell has some function like binmode in perl?

Tags: perl, powershell, stdout

call a script in powershell, and the script's console log is with utf-8 encoding.

what to auto encode stdout into cp936 encoding.

just like this in perl :

```
binmode STDOUT, ":cp936";
```

Comment: CP936 is simplified Chinese. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert(utf-8,gb2312,$stringtoconvert)
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx for the table of supported encodings.